# Symfony 4 Bug Vendor /route.php After server:run

Tags: php, symfony4

In Symfony 4, I have one bug when I use:

> php bin/console serve:run

```
[Thu Sep 27 19:11:00 2018] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 27 19:11:00 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Sites\Symfony4\vendor\symfony\web-server-bundle/Resources/router.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I use **composer install** before this command.

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Can you add more information?  I'm unsure if you are trying to start the dev server (in which case it's 'bin/console server:start') or something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that Avast quarantined my file. And since I was using it in silent mode, I did not see the notification.